# В мобильном приложении на React Native не сохраняется форматирование текста

Tags: javascript, парсер, react-native

В мобильном приложении на React Native не сохраняется форматирование - весь текст в одну строку выводит.

В решении как в этом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469570/how-can-i-insert-new-line-r-n-in-react-native-text-component придется парсить весь текст и вставлять в нужном месте. Мы ищем способ что-бы нативно поддерживало,
или библиотеку.

Нужен парсер управляющих символов на js, который находит в тексте \n или \r и заменяет их на {\n}.

Answer (score 1):

```
text.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '{"\\n"}')
```

Answer (score -1):

Для того, чтобы учитывались управляющие символы, нужно использовать CSS свойство `whiteSpace: 'pre'`. И писать текст не в тег, а в `state` или `props`, пример:

[image]